# Use different directory for snaps

Tags: snap

Currently all snaps are being stored in `/snap`. Since it's using up a lot of space, I'd like to move it to a different partition.

It it possible to just copy all the files and then symlink the folder?

Comment: Actually they're not in `/snap`, they're in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` and mounted in `/snap`. Take note not to look at the space used in `/snap`, because you're looking inside compressed snap files there. The space used is actually less than you see in `/snap` due to the compression.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu the `/snap` directory is under where snaps are mounted, and some symlinks to binaries. You don't want to move this around, as things will not behave as you expect (note in other distros that's `/var/lib/snapd/snap`). If you're using `du` to determine the amount of space used, you should pass `-x` (`--one-file-system`) so it does not go into the snaps themselves. Compare,

```
$ sudo du -sh /snap
8.6G    /snap
$ sudo du -shx /snap
108K    /snap
```

that second number is the actual space used. Those 8.6G aren't "used" anywhere, because snaps are stored compressed:

```
$ du -sh /var/lib/snapd/snaps
2.5G    /var/lib/snapd/snaps
```

---

[image: dangerous bend]
If you're running short of storage on the partition that holds `/var/lib/snapd/snaps` you could look into moving it (or even the whole of `/var/lib/snapd`) to a different partition. It's a little tricky because those files are mounted, but you can stop snapd (so it doesn't start a refresh in the middle of this), stop the mount units by hand, and then move them around safely. If you mount the new partition using a systemd mount unit it should figure out the ordering on its own (if you already have a partition and are moving them to a subdirectory, a bind mount unit will also work).